# Core Image ciContext.writeHEIFRepresentation() generates images with diagonal lines when using CICrop filter. How can I prevent this?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, core-image, heif

I am trying to generate **HEIF output files** but get strange diagonal lines when I do so.  None of the other output formats exhibit these strange lines.  See the image below.  The problem appears to be cropping but the errors only show in the HEIF output files.

I can replicate this with the following playground code which you can download from here https://duncangroenewald.com/files/SampleApps/CoreImageHEIFExporterBug-2.zip

I have a bug report with Apple and they mentioned "sub-pixel errors" - I have no idea what that is or why these would manifest only with the heif output format or how to prevent them - any ideas or does this just seem like a bug in the Apple code?

**EDIT**. To be clear this is not a playground issue since the problem occurs in a macOS application.

I suspect this must be a `CIContext` bug when generating HEIF output since it only manifests with heif output files.  However I know nothing about sub-pixel errors or why Apple think they should be relevant for this issue.  Perhaps someone with more Core Image knowledge might be able to suggest some possible solutions.

```
import Cocoa

let files = ["/Users/duncangroenewald/Development/Playgrounds/CoreImageHEIFExporterBug/DSC02022.ARW",
     "/Users/duncangroenewald/Development/Playgrounds/CoreImageHEIFExporterBug/DSC02018.ARW"
]

let destFilePath = "/Users/duncangroenewald/Development/Playgrounds/CoreImageHEIFExporterBug"

let destUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: destFilePath)

let exporter = Exporter()

var crops = [CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 5310, height: 3212),
             CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 5311, height: 3212),
             CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 5312, height: 3212),
             CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 5313, height: 3212)]


for file in files {
    exporter.processRAWFile(file, destPath: destFilePath, crops: crops)
}

print("Done!")

import AppKit
import CoreImage
import CoreImage.CIFilterBuiltins
import OSLog

public class Exporter {
    
    var formats: [String] = ["heif", "png"]
    
    // Get the CIContext
    let ciContext = CIContext()
    
    var imageOrientation: Int = 0
    var imageNativeSize: CGSize = .zero

    var crops: [CGRect] = [.zero]

    public init() {
        
    }
    
    public func processRAWFile(_ path: String, destPath: String, crops: [CGRect]) {
        
        print("processRAWFile XXX")
        self.crops = crops
        
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        
        let filename = url.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent
        
        let destDirUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: destPath)
        print("destDirUrl: \(destDirUrl)")
        
        for crop in crops {
        
            let cropName = "\(filename)_\(crop.width)x\(crop.height)_\(useDefaultRAW ? "default" : "")"
        
            for format in formats {
            let destUrl = destDirUrl.appendingPathComponent(cropName).appendingPathExtension(format)
            print("destFile: \(destUrl)")
        
                self.exportFile(url: url, destUrl: destUrl, crop: crop, format: format)
                
            }
          
        }
    }
    
    func exportFile(url: URL, destUrl: URL, crop: CGRect, format: String){
        print("exportFile \(url)")
        print("destFile: \(destUrl)")
        
        guard let rawFilter = CIFilter(imageURL: url, options: nil), let outputImage = rawFilter.outputImage else {
            print("Failed to load \(url.lastPathComponent) for exporting")
            return
        }
        
        let processImage = self.crop(outputImage, rect: crop)
        
        
        let options = [kCGImageDestinationLossyCompressionQuality as CIImageRepresentationOption: 1.0 as CGFloat]
        let colorSpace = CGColorSpace(name: CGColorSpace.sRGB)!
        let imgFormat = CIFormat.RGBA16
        
        do {
            
            switch format {
            case "tiff":
                try ciContext.writeTIFFRepresentation(of: processImage, to: destUrl, format: imgFormat, colorSpace: colorSpace, options: options)
            case "jpeg":
                try ciContext.writeJPEGRepresentation(of: processImage, to: destUrl, colorSpace: colorSpace, options: options)
            case "png":
                try ciContext.writePNGRepresentation(of: processImage, to: destUrl, format: imgFormat, colorSpace: colorSpace, options: options)
            case "heif":
                try ciContext.writeHEIFRepresentation(of: processImage, to: destUrl, format: imgFormat, colorSpace: colorSpace, options: options)
            default:
                try ciContext.writePNGRepresentation(of: processImage, to: destUrl, format: imgFormat, colorSpace: colorSpace, options: options)
            }
            
        } catch {
            print("Error exporting \(format): \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        
    }
    var useDefaultRAW: Bool = true

    func crop(_ ciImage: CIImage, rect: CGRect)->CIImage {
        if let cropped = self.cropFilter(ciImage, rect: rect) {
            return cropped
        } else {
            print("Error cropping image !")
            return ciImage
        }
    }
  
    
    func cropFilter(_ input: CIImage, rect: CGRect) -> CIImage? {
        
        
        // Getting a dashed border !!
        guard let cropFilter = CIFilter(name: "CICrop") else {
            print("Error no CICrop filter found !")
            return input
        }
        let ciVect = CIVector(cgRect: rect)
        cropFilter.setValue(input, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

        cropFilter.setValue(ciVect, forKey: "inputRectangle")

        return cropFilter.value(forKey: kCIOutputImageKey) as? CIImage
        
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Your topic is too broad.  We don't know if you are reporting an issue with Playground or an issue with Core Image or an issue with HEIF.

Comment: It's not a playground issue since this occurs in the macOS application.  Playground is just used to reproduce the issue.  Not quite sure how this can be a HEIF issue since that is a format specification.  Either I am using the APIs incorrectly or it is a bug in Core Image - it's not clear to me whether there is something wrong with the code given it works fine for all but HEIF output formats but perhaps there are some  cropping considerations I am not aware of to make sure you avoid sub-pixel errors.

Comment: I have the same issue with the diagonal lines, but only in some images output from some ciFilters. Possible internal tiling issue? Will work on narrowing down the circumstances that show the lines.

Comment: @WillLoew-Blosser - looks like it is a bug - try the macOS12 beta with Xcode 13 - seems it is fixed there by still not in 11.5 beta.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could find to work it around was to
render `CGImage` through the context first and then re-create `CIImage` from `CGImage`.

**EDIT**

```
let context = CIContext()
let fileURL = <URL to save location>
let ciImage = <Here is the image you got as output of filter>
let options = [kCGImageDestinationLossyCompressionQuality as CIImageRepresentationOption: 1.0 as CGFloat]
let colorSpace = CGColorSpace(name: CGColorSpace.sRGB)!
let imgFormat = CIFormat.RGBA16

// First we create a CGImage
let cgImage = context.createCGImage(ciImage, 
                                    from: ciImage.extent,
                                    format: imgFormat,
                                    colorSpace: colorSpace)

// Then we use this CGImage to re-create CIImage and save it
try context.writeHEIFRepresentation(
                of: CIImage(cgImage: cgImage),
                to: fileURL,
                format: imgFormat,
                colorSpace: colorSpace,
                options: options
            )
```

Comment: Could you please share some codes or examples with us? It would make your answer more complete and useful, thanks!